# Test coverage with JaCoCo and Ant for Sonar

Tags: java, ant, sonarqube, jacoco

I have adjusted Sonar part to show project fake test coverage - giving mock "jacoco.exec" file, so I need to have real file as a result of project analyse with JaCoCo.

I have Ant "build.xml" and try to implement two approaches for getting goal (both are described here http://eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/ant.html):

1. Using Ant's Java agent I have adjusted JVM option

   ```
   -agentvmparam:${somepath}\\lib\\jacocoagent.jar=destfile=D:\\jacoco.exec
   ```

and try to execute in build.xml

```
<project name="project" default="all" basedir="." xmlns:jacoco="antlib:org.jacoco.ant">
    <jacoco:agent property="agentvmparam"/>
```

Unfortunately, nothing happens.

2. Using JaCoCo `coverage` I try to run the following - but `java` tag is not specified and build failed:

   ```xml
   <project name="project" default="all" basedir="." xmlns:jacoco="antlib:org.jacoco.ant">
       <target name="jacoco" description="Code coverage reporting" xmlns:jacoco="antlib:org.jacoco.ant">
           <jacoco:coverage>
               <java classname="org.jacoco.examples.HelloJaCoCo" fork="true">
                   <classpath>
                       <pathelement location="./bin"/>
                   </classpath>
               </java>
           </jacoco:coverage>
           <jacoco:coverage>
               <junit fork="true" forkmode="once">
                   <test name="org.jacoco.examples.HelloJaCoCoTest"/>
                   <classpath>
                       <pathelement location="./bin"/>
                   </classpath>
               </junit>
           </jacoco:coverage>
       </target>
   ```